# Spring Framework javadoc error

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Iam new to Spring framework. Iam on following link:

http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/mongodb

When I click "API JAVADOC", I get 404 error on following link.

http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/apidocs/

Can some one guide me what is wrong in url and how it can be rectified.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It simply means that there is a mistake with the link. It's not your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest javadoc can always be found under http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/api/. I've fixed the broken link on the Spring Data MongoDB project homepage.

Answer (score 0):

The main directory containing all docs is [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/)

So you can go to docs for any version. For example for [1.1.0.GA](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/api/)